# Notification of new telegram private channel member/subscribers

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

Is there any way to set up a notification system that sends the username of every new member/subscriber that joins your own private telegram channel to you, via message/email/any other method.

Has anybody done this before or have any ideas about the most appropriate way to do this, could a bot do this? Or would you need a program another app based on telegram or an applet?

Can't find anything online!

Comment: No, you can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SubTrackBot](https://t.me/subscriber_update_bot)

You need to add this bot to your channel just as admin.(No further permissions are required)

It sends a message, which includes a user and your channel details, to you each time a user joins or leaves your channel.

For private channels, if you give "Add Subscribers" permission, it'll embed your channel link in the message so that you can navigate to your channel easily. (It's optional; the bot works without it as well.)

Disclosure: I am the developer of SubTrackBot mentioned in this answer.